# will play integrity is paid after 10000 request?

Tags: android, google-play-integrity-api

I am going to implement Google Play Integrity in my Android app using "Use Google Cloud Console" method .I want to know after i enabled "Google Play Integrity API" from Google Cloud Console limit is 10000 request per day for cloud console? and after 10000 request will pay any charged  or (amount will debited) autometically cloud console?

Any one has any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This quota is a hard cap on the number of requests per day.

The documentation ([here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview#have-anti-abuse) and [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#increase-daily-max)) is pretty clear that integrity checks are resource intensive and should not be called very often, especially if you are still making 'classic' integrity requests.

> The Play Integrity API works best when used alongside other signals as part of your overall anti-abuse strategy and not as your sole anti-abuse mechanism. Use this API in conjunction with other appropriate security best practices for your app.

> Even with an increased daily maximum, you should continue to limit classic requests per user to infrequent, high-value actions to preserve user data and battery.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't be charged anything, you will start to receive "quota is exceeded" error (until the next day). During this time you won't be able to get new integrity tokens from the devices.

More information is here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#increase-daily-max